Cannot navigate to NavDeepLinkRequest{ uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/auth }. Navigation graph has not been set
Here's my code for handling navigation during specific errors and changes in auth state:
var error by rememberSaveable {
    mutableStateOf<String?>(null)
}
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    context.authDataStore.data.collectLatest {
        val loggedOut = it[loggedOutDataStore] ?: false
        val currRoute = navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route
        if (currRoute != null) {
        //if logged out and not in auth, navigate there
            if (loggedOut && currRoute != OtherScreens.Auth.route) {
                navController.navigate(OtherScreens.Auth.route) { popUpTo(0)}
            }
            if (currRoute != OtherScreens.Auth.route && currRoute != OtherScreens.AccountDelete.route) {
                // if error was not null or empty but now it is means there's no error anymore and we can navigate to Main
                if (!error.isNullOrEmpty() && it[errorKey].isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    // use popUpTo(NavScreens.Main.route) to not reinitialize view model
                    // if already navigated to Main before
                    navController.navigate(NavScreens.Main.route) {
                        popUpTo(NavScreens.Main.route)
                        launchSingleTop = true
                    }
                }
                error = it[errorKey]
                if (!error.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    navController.navigate(OtherScreens.Error.route) {popUpTo(0) }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
NavHost(
                navController, startDestination,
                enterTransition = { slideInHorizontally { -it } },
                exitTransition = { fadeOut() },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(innerPadding)
            ) {
                composable(NavScreens.Main.route) {
                    MainScreen(navController)
                }
                composable(NavScreens.ThoughtTracker.route) {
                    ThoughtTrackerScreen(navController)
                }
                composable(NavScreens.Stats.route) {
                    MeditationStatsScreen()
                }
                composable(NavScreens.ChatsScreen.route) {
                    ChatsScreen(navController)
                }
                composable(NavScreens.SettingsScreen.route) {
                    SettingsScreen()
                }
                composable(OtherScreens.Auth.route) {
                    AuthScreen(onNavigateToMain = {
                        navController.navigate(NavScreens.Main.route) { popUpTo(NavScreens.Main.route) }
                    })
                } }

While tests were performed by Google Play review one device reported having the following  exception, although my own tests did not:

Cannot navigate to NavDeepLinkRequest{ uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/auth }. Navigation graph has not been set

Also, if anyone knows a better way to achieve what the code above does, I'd be very grateful.
